# This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it when try to download the file in Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, file-copying

I have a cloud functions that copy and paste a file from one standard bucket to a Nearline bucket. I also tried to save the file by opening as a dataframe and write it as dask dataframe. They both worked but Every time I try to download the file through the
[GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqsKB.png) I get the an XML error message as stated below. Does anyone know why this is happening? How Can I prevent it to happen?

> This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it

```
import base64
import json
from google.cloud import storage
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd

def hello_pubsub(event, context):
    """Triggered from a message on a Cloud Pub/Sub topic.
    Args:
         event (dict): Event payload.
         context (google.cloud.functions.Context): Metadata for the event.
    """
    print('here')
    print(event)
    pubsub_message = base64.b64decode(event['data']).decode('utf-8')
    payload = json.loads(pubsub_message)

    bucket_name = payload['data']['bucket_name']
    print(bucket_name)
    
    blob_name = payload['data']['file_name']
    print(blob_name)

    destination_bucket_name = 'infobip-email-uploaded'

    #destination_blob_name = blob_name[0:10]+'.csv'
    destination_blob_name = 'ddf-*.csv'


    df = pd.read_excel('gs://'+bucket_name+'/'+blob_name, sheet_name='Data', engine='xlrd')
    print('excel has been read')

    ddf = dd.from_pandas(df,npartitions=1, sort=True)
    print('dataframe has been transformed into dask')

    path = 'gs://'+destination_bucket_name +'/'+ destination_blob_name
    print('path is')
    print(path)
    ddf.to_csv(path, index=False, sep=',', header=False)

    destination_blob_name = blob_name[0:10]+'.xlsx'
    copy_blob(bucket_name,blob_name,destination_bucket_name,destination_blob_name)
    print('File has been successfully copied')

    delete_blob(bucket_name,blob_name)
    print('File has been successfully deleted')
    
    return '200'

def copy_blob(bucket_name, blob_name, destination_bucket_name, destination_blob_name):
    """Copies a blob from one bucket to another with a new name."""
    # bucket_name = "your-bucket-name"
    # blob_name = "your-object-name"
    # destination_bucket_name = "destination-bucket-name"
    # destination_blob_name = "destination-object-name"

    storage_client = storage.Client()

    source_bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    source_blob = source_bucket.blob(blob_name)
    destination_bucket = storage_client.bucket(destination_bucket_name)

    blob_copy = source_bucket.copy_blob(
        source_blob, destination_bucket, destination_blob_name
    )

    print(
        "Blob {} in bucket {} copied to blob {} in bucket {}.".format(
            source_blob.name,
            source_bucket.name,
            blob_copy.name,
            destination_bucket.name,
        )
    )

def delete_blob(bucket_name, blob_name):
    """Deletes a blob from the bucket."""
    # bucket_name = "your-bucket-name"
    # blob_name = "your-object-name"

    storage_client = storage.Client()

    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(blob_name)
    blob.delete()

    print("Blob {} deleted.".format(blob_name))
```

Comment: Are you able to download the files using gsutil commands?

Comment: I did not try that but seemed like it was temporarily because when I try to download the file after some time it worked! So I guess they are just not immediately available. Thanks for your help though!